# Pointer Array shared between OpenCL kernels

Tags: arrays, pointers, memory, opencl

Is it possible to share an array of pointers between multiple kernels in OpenCL. If so, how would I go about implementing it? If I am not completely mistaken - which may though be the case - the only way of sharing things between kernels would be a shared cl_mem, however I also think these cannot contain pointers.

Comment: Please consider removing the C tag as this question seems not to be about an issue specific to the C programming language.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in OpenCL 1.x because host and device have completely separate memory spaces, so a buffer containing host pointers makes no sense on the device side.

However, OpenCL 2.0 supports Shared Virtual Memory (SVM) and so memory containing pointers is legal because the host and device share an address space. There are three different levels of granularity though, which will limit what you can have those pointers point to. In the coarsest case they can only refer to locations within the same buffer or other SVM buffers currently owned by the device. Yes, `cl_mem` is still the way to pass in a buffer to a kernel, but in OpenCL 2.0 with SVM that buffer may contain pointers.

**Edit/Addition:** OP points out they just want to share pointers between kernels. If these are just device pointers, then you can store them in the buffer in one kernel and read them from the buffer in another kernel. They can only refer to __global, not __local memory. And without SVM they can't be used on the host. The host will of course need to allocate the buffer and pass it to both kernels for their use. As far as the host is concerned, it's just opaque memory. Only the kernels know they are __global pointers.

Comment: I know that host pointers won't work on the gpu. I also know about SVM, but that's not what I'm asking about. I just want to share an array of pointers between several different kernels.

Comment: Device pointers? Then just store them in the buffer in one kernel and read them from the buffer in another kernel. They can't be used on the host though. The host will of course need to allocate the buffer and pass it to both kernels for their use.

Comment: well, the question is about how to do exactly that.

Comment: It just said "pointers"; I'm sorry I didn't realize you meant "device only pointers". So I added to my answer know that I understand that.

Comment: "well, the question is about how to do exactly that" as far as I know, you cannot simply store an array of pointers in a buffer.

Comment: Why do you think it would not work? Do you think the starting address of a buffer moves around between kernels? If that is a concern, and if the addresses are all within the buffer, then just store the offset within the buffer instead. Then even if the buffer somehow moves around in memory between your two kernels, the offsets will remain the same.

Comment: "__kernel void main(__global Datatype ** name)" does not work: " kernel parameter cannot be declared as a pointer to a pointer"

Comment: Can you declare it as a pointer to void or a pointer to a simple type and then cast it inside the kernel?

Comment: @Dithermaster, I would like to ask you a question. I recently ask a question on a similar topic (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52276989/using-structure-as-buffer-holder), and I noticed that, yes starting address of a buffer moves around between kernels (at least that the other users seems to answer me), and what I can notice on Nvidia devices. But I would like to understand what you means by "offset". A position inside the same buffer right ? I know this might be old, but Im questioning myself on something really similar. Maybe this applies only with SVM ? (I only work with CL 1.2)

Comment: I saw that post about buffers moving around. I learned something new there. By offset, that means storing the index that would get added to a pointer. So if you had an array of vertexes and an array of edges, instead of having the edges point to the vertexes directly, you'd store the index. Then if the vertex point changes from kernel to kernel, you would just use the latest pointer and the index (as in, `base_ptr[index]`). The index is the offset into the array. Won't work for stand-alone objects, just arrays of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, but I managed to get around it by using a simple pointer structure.I have doubts about the fact that someone says that buffers change their position in memory,perhaps this is true for some special cases.But this definitely cannot happen while the kernel is working with it. I have not tested it on different video cards, but on nvidia(cl 1.2) it works perfectly, so I can access data from an array that was not even passed as an argument into the kernel.

```
typedef struct
{  
   __global volatile point_dataT* point;//pointer to another struct in different buffer
}   pointerBufT;

__kernel void tester(__global pointerBufT * pointer_buf){
printf("Test id: %u\n",pointer_buf[coord.x+coord.y*img_width].point->id);//Retrieving information from an array not passed to the kernel
}
```

I know that this is a late reply, but for some reason I have only come across negative answers to similar questions, or a suggestion to use indexes instead of pointers. While a structure with a pointer inside works great.